# Live Video Streaming using Raspberry Pi and C#

Tags: c#, .net, raspberry-pi, live-streaming, windows-10-iot-core

I'm in a uni project of live Streaming the video (Taken from a Web Cam) and stream it to the desktop using C# (UWP, Windows 10 IoT Core). Even though I found some projects doing the server side implementation in Java (For Rasp) and Client side using UWP I couldn't find any Projects regarding Server side programming in C#.

Plus, is it really possible to do such server side programming using C# for live streaming as this Microsoft link say it isn't.
 [View the Microsoft Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/496a5e9a-aff6-4886-9887-d0257f2cc49c/how-can-i-stream-video-from-windows-10-iot-core-on-raspberry-pi?forum=WindowsIoT)

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Regards, 
T.S.

Comment: Have you check [this project](https://github.com/davetoland/VideoSocketServer)?

Comment: Thanks, This would do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > Even though I found some projects doing the server side implementation in Java (For Rasp) and Client side using UWP I couldn't find any Projects regarding Server side programming in C#.

There is another project I have coded and tested successfully. You could have a reference if it could help you.

In the MyVideoServer App the important is getting the camera id and previewFrame of the video. `previewFrame = await MyMediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame);`Then send video stream to client through streamSocketClient.`await streamSocketClient.sendBuffer(buffer);`

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        InitializeCameraAsync();
        InitSocket();
    }

    MediaCapture MyMediaCapture;
    VideoFrame videoFrame;
    VideoFrame previewFrame;
    IBuffer buffer;

    DispatcherTimer timer;
    StreamSocketListenerServer streamSocketSrv;
    StreamSocketClient streamSocketClient;

    private async void InitializeCameraAsync()
    {
        var allVideoDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
        DeviceInformation cameraDevice = allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault();
        var mediaInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id };
        MyMediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

        try
        {
            await MyMediaCapture.InitializeAsync(mediaInitSettings);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {

        }

        PreviewControl.Height = 180;
        PreviewControl.Width = 240;
        PreviewControl.Source = MyMediaCapture;

        await MyMediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
        videoFrame = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, 240, 180, 0);
        buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer((uint)(240 * 180 * 8));
    }
```

Then the key server code is trying to create a server and connect client by socket communication in InitSocket function. StreamSocketListenerServer should be created as an object and started. At the same time the server ip port is setup.`streamSocketSrv = new StreamSocketListenerServer();
await streamSocketSrv.start("22333");`Last but not least, the Timer_Tick will send video stream to client every 100ms.

```
    private async void InitSocket()
    {
        streamSocketSrv = new StreamSocketListenerServer();
        await streamSocketSrv.start("22333");

        streamSocketClient = new StreamSocketClient();

        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }
```

Following you could deploy MyVideoServer App on Raspberry Pi 3.
[image]
Then you could deploy MyVideoClient App on PC. Then enter Raspberry Pi 3 IP Address and click Connect button. The video stream would display on the App.
[image]

This is the [sample](https://github.com/we4690/WinIotVideo) code and you could take a reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot and I'll try it :-)

Comment: Can I add audio to this solution? If I can how to do that?